# TagHelperAttribute.Value is type string, not type ModelExpression, for novel tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a correctly working tag helper for the `<select>` element which contains the following working code:

```
TagHelperAttribute forAttribute;
if (!context.AllAttributes.TryGetAttribute("asp-for", out forAttribute))
{
    throw new Exception("No asp-for attribute found.");
}

var forInfo = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression)forAttribute.Value;
```

I have the same code in a different tag helper, for a novel element I'm calling `<date-picker>`.  In this second tag helper, the cast to `ModelExpression` fails because `forAttribute.Value` is, in fact, not a `ModelExpression` but rather a string (it is the property name, "DueDate", to which I'm trying to bind the tag).

It seems my novel `date-picker` tag is not aware that the `asp-for` value should be applied to the Razor page model.

How can I ensure that my `date-picker` receives a correct `ModelExpression` on which to base my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure your attribute has the proper binding, you need to define a property in your tag helper class, with the `HtmlAttributeName` attribute. For example:

```cs
[HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
```

The reason why the attribute is required is that the `HtmlAttributeNameAttribute` class does a lot behind the scene to bind the proper value. You can see how the value is bound on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/46549972016e0f8f9a870185e74de215a0722d13/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor/DefaultTagHelperDescriptorFactory.cs#L185).

Also, this simplifies how you access the value of the attribute, as you don't need to go through the entire list. So instead of this:

```cs
TagHelperAttribute forAttribute;
if (!context.AllAttributes.TryGetAttribute("asp-for", out forAttribute))
{
    throw new Exception("No asp-for attribute found.");
}

var forInfo = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression)forAttribute.Value;
```

You can write :

```cs
// you can call the For property
var forInfo = For;
```

Answer (score 0):

create the attribute TAG and property as shown below:

```
[HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
public ModelExpression AspFor { get; set; }
```

Access the attribute model value,name etc. as in the following way:

```
AspFor.Name
AspFor.Model
```